# What code should I put inside the Android Lifecycle method?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I am new in Android. I am currently developing a game and when I press the back button I realize that my activity's state is not saved so I search and I found out about Android Lifecycle. I read it and now i know how they work but the thing is I don't know how to pause and resume my activity or What code should I use because it is the auto-generated grid and my timer is CountDownTimer.

When I press the Back button this Activity is what appears.
[GameModeActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6OHT.jpg)

Now i want to detect if the game is still going on .. so if I click again the game mode this is what should appear.
[GamePlayActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRFL9.jpg)

The problem is The grid was back to its normal state. and when I click a button timer never runs. If possible i want to restore the player's progress (like the position of mines, the flags, and the timer itself.).

My question is ... Is there a specific code to get the whole state of activity? so that i can just pause it and when i came back it will just resume?

This is the code of timer and grid in GameEngine class:

```
public static GameEngine getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new GameEngine();
    }
    return instance;
}
private GameEngine() {
}

public void startit() {
    countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
        TextView timer = (TextView) ((GamePlayActivity) context).findViewById(R.id.tvTimeValue);

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText("Times up!");
            timer.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }.start();

}


public static void cancel() {
    if (countdowntimer != null) {
        countdowntimer.cancel();
        countdowntimer = null;
    }
}

public void createGrid(Context context) {
    Log.e("GameEngine", "Creating Grid..");
    this.context = context;


    int[][] GeneratedGrid = Generator.generate(bombnumber, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setGrid(context, GeneratedGrid);
}

private void setGrid(final Context context, final int[][] grid) {
    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
            if (MinesweeperGrid[x][y] == null) {
                MinesweeperGrid[x][y] = new Cell(context, x, y);
            }
            MinesweeperGrid[x][y].setValue(grid[x][y]);
            MinesweeperGrid[x][y].invalidate();
        }
    }
}

public Cell getCellposition(int position) {
    int x = position % WIDTH;
    int y = position / WIDTH;

    return MinesweeperGrid[x][y];
}

public Cell getCellposition(int x, int y) {
    return MinesweeperGrid[x][y];
}
```

I call the GameEngine.getInstance().createGrid(this) class in onCreate method of GamePlayActivity
And when I press the Back button on phone it will go to the previous activity which is GameModeActivity.

Comment: Please, define `... the Android Lifecycle method`